# Deserialize JSON into struct with duplicate JSON mapping

Tags: go

I am trying to deserialize JSON which looks like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/patternedrecurrence?view=graph-rest-1.0):

```
{
  "pattern": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recurrencePattern"},
  "range": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.recurrenceRange"}
}
```

For this I created several structs where the first one looks like this:

```
type MSPatternedRecurrence struct {
    Pattern MSRecurrencePattern `json:"@odata.type"`
    Range   MSRecurrenceRange   `json:"@odata.type"`
}
```

However go vet throws an error like this:

```
struct field Range repeats json tag "@odata.type"
```

What is the right way to create a struct in this situation?

type MSPatternedRecurrence struct {
    Pattern MSRecurrencePattern `json:"@odata.type"`
    Range   MSRecurrenceRange   `json:"@odata.type"`
}

```
type MSRecurrencePattern struct {
    DayOfMonth     int      `json:"dayOfMonth"`
    DayOfWeek      []string `json:"daysOfWeek"`
    FirstDayOfWeek string   `json:"firstDayOfWeek"`
    Index          string   `json:"index"`
    Interval       int      `json:"interval"`
    Month          int      `json:"month"`
    Type           string   `json:"type"`
}

type MSRecurrenceRange struct {
    EndDate             string `json:"endDate"`
    NumberOfOccurrences int    `json:"numberOfOccurrences"`
    RecurrenceTimeZone  string `json:"recurrenceTimeZone"`
    StartDate           string `json:"startDate"`
    Type                string `json:"type"`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the error clearly states you're trying to map two struct fields to the same JSON field name, which you cannot do; also, the definitions for the types used for those fields aren't given, but it seems unlikely they're correct given that the JSON has them both as simple strings.

You have two fields, `pattern` and `range`. Each's value is an object. Those objects each have a field named `@odata.type`. I.e.:

```
type Odata struct {
    Type string `json:"@odata.type"`
}

type MSPatternedRecurrence struct {
    Pattern Odata
    Range   Odata
}
```

You might find the [JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) tool useful. For this JSON, it outputs:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Pattern struct {
        OdataType string `json:"@odata.type"`
    } `json:"pattern"`
    Range struct {
        OdataType string `json:"@odata.type"`
    } `json:"range"`
}
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with rest of the structs. Go vet on 1.2.15 doesn't throw any errors on 1.12.5,  but on 1.12.1 throws this error. I was hoping this is just a bug which got fixed in a later version. Also, the JSON structure is coming from Microsoft Graph API. This is something that I have no control over.

Comment: The JSON structure isn't the problem, and it's not a bug. You can't map two struct fields to one label, but you don't need to because that's not how the JSON is structured. You updated the question with more structs but they don't match the sample JSON; can you give a full example JSON document? Or just take a full document and feed it into the tool I linked in the answer?

Comment: I think I know where I made the mistake. Thanks for sending the link to the JSON To GO tool. Very useful.